# how to modify my R code to accelerate computational speed

Tags: r

Here are my R code. Could you please give me some advice so that can accelerate the computational speed :)

First, the function `myfun()`generates a complex number.

Second, I compute the elements of matrix M using `myfun()`.

```
myfun<-function(a,b,nq,ul,uk)
 {
   m<-seq(1,(nq/2)+1,length=(nq/2)+1);
   k<-m;

   D<-matrix(NA,nrow = length(k),ncol = length(k)); 

  for(i in 1:length(k)) # row
    for(j in 1:length(m)) # column
    {
      D[i,j]<-(2/nq)*cos(((j-1)*(i-1)*pi)/(nq*0.5))
    }

    D[,1]<-D[,1]*0.5;
    D[,ncol(D)]<-D[,ncol(D)]*0.5;   

    # compute the vector v
    vseq<-seq(2,nq-2,by=2);
    vr<-2/(1-vseq^2);
    vr<-c(1,vr,1/(1-nq*nq));
    v<-matrix(vr,ncol=1);  # v is a N by 1 matrix

    # compute the vector w, length(w)=nq/2+1

    h<-function(x,ul,uk)
     {
      ((b-a)/2)*(exp((b-a)/2*x+(a+b)/2)+1)^(1i*uk)*cos(((b-a)/2*x+(a+b)/2-a)*ul)
     }

     w<-matrix(rep(NA,length(v)),ncol=1);

     for(i in 1:length(w))
      {
        w[i]<-h((cos((i-1)*pi/nq)),ul,uk)+h((-cos((i-1)*pi/nq)),ul,uk)
      }

      res<-t(t(D)%*%v)%*%w; # each element of matrix M

      return(res)
      }
```

Next, compute each element of matrix M. The N-th column and N-th row are zeros.

```
   matrix.M<-matrix(0,ncol = N,nrow = N);

   for(i in 1:N-1)
    for(j in 1:N-1)
   {
    matrix.M[i,j]<-myfun(a,b,nq,i-1,j-1)
   }
```

We can set parameters as

```
   a<--173.2;
   b<-78;
   alpha<-0.24;
   Dt<-0.1;
   M<-1000;
   N<-150;
   u<-seq(1,150,by=1)*pi/(b-a);
   nq<-3000;
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: In the definition of `h` should that be  `*x+(a+b)/2-a)` without the period?

Comment: Yes, without the period. @ekstroem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for speeding the function up. I use three "tricks":

1. Vectorize as many functions as possible
2. Use the `outer` function instead of a double loop
3. Use the hidden gem `crossprod` for the final matrix products

   myfun<-function(a,b,nq,ul,uk) {
       m<-seq(1,(nq/2)+1,length=(nq/2)+1);
       k<-m;

   ```
   ## Use outer to compute the elements of the matrix
   D <- outer(1:length(k), 1:length(m), function(i, j) {(2/nq)*cos(((j-1)*(i-1)*pi)/(nq*0.5))} )

   D[,1]<-D[,1]*0.5;
   D[,ncol(D)]<-D[,ncol(D)]*0.5;

                                       # compute the vector v                                                                             
   vseq<-seq(2,nq-2,by=2);
   vr<-2/(1-vseq^2);
   vr<-c(1,vr,1/(1-nq*nq));
   v<-matrix(vr,ncol=1);  # v is a N by 1 matrix                                                                                          

   h<-function(x,ul,uk) {
       ((b-a)/2)*(exp((b-a)/2*x+(a+b)/2)+1)^(1i*uk)*cos(((b-a)/2*x+(a+b)/2-a)*ul)
   }

   ## Compute the full w vector in one go    
   vect <- seq_along(v)-1
   w <- h((cos(vect*pi/nq)),ul,uk) + h((-cos(vect*pi/nq)),ul,uk)

   ## Compute the cross products. 
   res <- crossprod(crossprod(D, v), w)

   return(res)
   ```

   }

I think this should save around 80% of the time compared to the original function. The time hog was the initial computation of `D`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help :) These 'tricks' are helpful! @ekstroem